# MYSQL, Creating a view and pulling information from two tables

Tags: mysql, view

Okay so I have two tables:

hscust and hssales_rep

I need to create a view that shows me the reps fname and lname (as well as the customers) and show how much the customer is over on there credit balance.

This is the code I have:

```
CREATE VIEW OverLimit AS 
SELECT 
    CONCAT(hssales_rep.last,hssales_rep.first) AS Rep,     
    CONCAT(hscust.last,hscust.first) AS Cust, 
    SUM(credit_limit - balance)
FROM hscust 
INNER JOIN hssales_rep ON hscust.sales_rep = hssales_rep.repid
```

And it returns an empty result.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[salesrep table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4bz3.png)
[cust table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1h5O.png)

Comment: Any sample data you can share?

Comment: I added the tables that Im working on to the question

Comment: Your statement seems to work. You really need to provide sample data in a **`create table`** followed by **`insert into`** statements fashion, not a picture format) so that we can **reproduce** the problem.

Comment: It gives me an empty set though. & sorry Im new to the site so I dont know how to give you sample data in the form you want it

Comment: First of all script the tables: `create table blabla (...)`. Then write statements to insert some data: `insert into blabla values (1,'yy,'xx',...)`. You can create a rextester demo (www.rextester.com) if you want.

Comment: The `CREATE VIEW` command executes correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CREATE VIEW` statement doesn't return a resultset.

A `SELECT` statement can return an empty resultset. But we'd expect the `SELECT` statement in your view definition to return either a single row, or throw an error.

I suggest you break this down a bit.

**1)** What problem is being solved by the `CREATE VIEW` statement. Why do you need a view?

**2)** Before you write a `CREATE VIEW` statement, first develop and test a `SELECT` statement that returns the required resultset. Do that *before* you put that into a view definition.

I also strongly recommend that you qualify *all* column references in the SELECT statement either with the table name or (preferably) a short table alias.

If you want to return a row for each `Cust` with an aggregate function (e.g. `SUM`) in your SELECT list, then add an appropriate `GROUP BY` clause to your `SELECT` statement.

It's not clear why we would want to use a SUM aggregate function.

The difference between "credit_limit" and "balance" would be the available (remaining) credit. A negative value would indicate the balance was "over" the credit limit.

```
SELECT CONCAT(r.last,r.first)      AS Rep
     , CONCAT(c.last,c.first)      AS Cust
     , c.credit_limit - c.balance  AS available_credit
  FROM hscust c
  JOIN hssales_rep r 
    ON c.sales_rep=r.repid
 ORDER
    BY CONCAT(r.last,r.first)
     , CONCAT(c.last,c.first)
     , c.custid
```

If we only want to return rows for customers that are "over" their credit limit, we can add a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT CONCAT(r.last,r.first)      AS Rep
     , CONCAT(c.last,c.first)      AS Cust
     , c.credit_limit - c.balance  AS available_credit
  FROM hscust c
  JOIN hssales_rep r 
    ON c.sales_rep=r.repid
 WHERE c.credit_limit - c.balance < 0
 ORDER
    BY CONCAT(r.last,r.first)
     , CONCAT(c.last,c.first)
     , c.custid
```

Again, get a `SELECT` statement working (returning the required resultset)  *before* you wrap it in a `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: Ohhh I see! I understand it now, Thanks so much!